# most efficient way to send dynamic columns

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Pretty difficult to explain, but here goes... We are currently working with a procedure which returns dynamic columns, 
ie column header is a date, and the number of columns can be x

```
 Type          12/12/2014    19/12/2014    26/12/2014
   1                2             3             1
   2                5             4             3
```

Which is the best way to handle this with a data reader. 
Currently, the database team are returning the data in the current format with the columns being dynamic, we know where a row ends, and a new one begins by the type, so, type 1 is one row, type 2 is the second row etc:-

```
column         data     Type
12/12/2014       2        1
19/12/2014       3        1
26/12/2014       1        1
12/12/2014       5        2
19/12/2014       4        2
26/12/2014       3        2
```

Within the .net application we build up a list of lists (which represent columns and rows)

```
List<TableColumn> ltc = new List<TableColumn>();
        List<List<TableColumn>> lltc = new List<List<TableColumn>>();

using (SqlDataReader rdr = (SqlDataReader)Database.ExecuteReader(com))
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        // If new ID or ID doesnt == the previous then create a new row
                        if (oc == "" || oc != rdr["Type"].ToSafeString())
                        {
                            if (oc != "")
                            {
                                lltc.Add(ltc);
                                ltc = new List<TableColumn>();
                            }
                        }
                        ltc.Add(new TableColumn(rdr["Column"].ToSafeString(), rdr["Data"].ToSafeString());
                        oc = rdr["type"].ToSafeString();
                    }
                }
```

The procedure can return a fair amount of data, (288 columns over the 8 rows for example)

Timing wise, its taking around 1.5 seconds to return the data from the database, and then another 1.2  second to actually create the list of lists via the data reader.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to handle this? as 1.2 + seconds min to create the model seems quite long.. The data will actually be displayed on the front end as a table.

Just to add, this is a web API MVC 4 application.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: This is called `Pivoting` and can be done in SQL

Comment: yes, however, if the data was returned as a normal table, it would be impossible to create a model, as we do not know how many columns are returned, they are dynamic, I think I'm correct in saying that..?

Comment: I must admit I'm not a ASP guy, I come from winforms. But surely you can bind a grid (and it can auto-populate columns) in ASP.NET. You can return a `DataTable` and bind the UI grid to that.

Comment: you can if the data layer returns a data table, and you simply bind to that call.. however, our application gathers the data in the web api, places it into an API Model and then passes this to the front end using JSON, But to build that model requires looping through the data, which seems to be taking almost as long as the sp takes to get it..

Comment: Pivot the data at SQL end and then bind data to datagrid. In other words get SQL to produce the data in the format your need first.

Comment: @mych thank you for your response, however, we are using MVC so no data bind to data grids, we need to create a model, and pass this to the view.. the model is being created as above,

Comment: are you simply wanting to display a grid, or do you need model binding to work on form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have handled this scenario as follows:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1    val11   val12   val13   val14
Row2    val21   val22   val23   val24
Row3    val31   val32   val33   val34
```

The view model would look like:

```
class GridModel 
{
    public ColumnModel[] Columns { get; set; }
    public GridRow[] Rows { get; set; }
}
class ColumnModel
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnLabel { get; set; }
    // other relevant column metadata for sorting, formatting, etc
}
class GridRow
{
    public string[] HiddenFields { get; set; }
    public string[] VisibleFields { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a View to render a ColumnModel:

```
@model ColumnModel
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ColumnLabel)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ColumnName)
</td>
```

a GridRow:

```
@model GridRow
<tr>
    <!-- loop through GridRow.VisibleFields to render TDs -->
</tr>
```

and finally a GridModel:

```
@model GridModel

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Columns)
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Rows)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will support arbitrary numbers of columns. To handle field formatting and such, you can attach metadata to your ColumnModel object, and reference the associated metadata as you are rendering the GridRows

Comment: BTW, this assumes you are getting the data back from sql without the pivot you're currently using

Comment: thank you, how would the model be populated from data access layer tho using a sqlDatareader?

Comment: I'm not at my computer to show some code, but you'll read the column names like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107 and get the values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I've never actually done this, I don't know if it will work or be faster, its just what came to mind when I read your post.

Instead of creating list of lists of data and stuff. Try creating a `List<dynamic>`, for each row you want to display, create a new `ExpandoObject` as a `IDictionary<string, string>` (assuming all your values are strings), then Dynamically add each Property to the object.
Now create grid headers for each one of these properties, and use the `List<dynamic>` as your data source.

The code to create a row, and add a property would looks something like this...

```
var row = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, string>;
row.Add("PropertyName", "value");
```